# I like to retrieve three values in a record from Mysql through PHP(using '?' AND '&') and send it to the other form using $_GET method

Tags: php

*

I like to retrieve three values in a record from Mysql through PHP(using '?' AND '&') and send it to the other form using $_GET method

*`// form sending values form1

```
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
 mysql_select_db("xxxxxx_Database",$connection);
 $v= mysql_query("Select * from patient_details order by P_id");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($v))
{ 
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['P_id']."</td><td>".$row['P_name']."</td><td>".$row['P_age']."       </td><td>"."<a href=Editing_Patient_Detail.php>Edit</a>   </td><td><a href=Delete_Patient_Detail.php?P_id=".$row['P_id']."&P_name=".$row['P_name']."&P_age="."row['P_age']".">Delete</a>";
}
          mysql_close( $connection);


 // form recieving the get values


 $connection=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
           mysql_select_db("Aravind_Database",$connection);
           if ($_GET['P_id']!= '')
          {     
        $v= mysql_query(" Select * from patient_details order by P_id");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($v))

    {   
      if ($row['P_id'] == $_GET['P_id'])
     {
                               ?>
              <input type="text" value='<?php $_GET['P_id']?>' /><br>
        <input type="text" width="145" value='<?php $_GET['P_name']?>' /><br>
        <input type="text" value    ='<?php $_GET['P_age']?>' /><br> <?php 
       break;
      }
        }
  }

// I am recieving only the P_id and P_name values, I can't recieve the P_age value     through //get "Sorry friends, while pasting on the website I typed it wrongly (P_age)"

            `
```

Comment: You should update the query to:
$v= mysql_query(" Select * from patient_details WHERE P_id = "(int)$_GET['P_id']);
There are loads of issues with this block of codes, for example you didn't echo the value here "value='<?php $_GET['P_id']?>"

Answer (score 0):

That is because you **are** only sending the id and name:
[a href=Delete_Patient_Detail.php?P_id=".$row['P_id']."&P_name=".$row['P_name']."&x="."10".">Delete[/a>";

To make it work, you'd have to add that parameter:

[a href=Delete_Patient_Detail.php?P_id=".$row['P_id']."&P_name=".$row['P_name']."&P_age=".$row['P_age']."&x="."10".">Delete[/a>";

Comment: Thank you, Dennis. But it was my typo while I pasting it on the website. It doesn't even shows the option in link location(URL) while I place mouse over the "Delete" link

Answer (score 0):

did you sure you send all 3 params, its look like you send only 2

```
href=Delete_Patient_Detail.php?P_id=".$row['P_id']."&P_name=".$row['P_name']."&x="."10".
```

you miss send the `P_age`

```
&P_age=".$row['P_age']."
```

Comment: I send the last param as well , its my typo. while pasting on the website.